# What does Rumi say/sing at the end of the OP for Tonari no Seki-Kun?

Tags: tonari-no-seki-kun

At the end of the Opening for *Tonari no Seki-Kun*, Seki holds up a microphone to Rumi, at which point she says to the rhythm of the music something like "Yama tay!". No translation is presented. What did she say?

It is a cute OP.  During it, Seki is developing an animation that includes both Rumi and himself. (IMO this is essentially a very funny yet fitting meta commentary on the series.) You see him with what is probably a character summary of Rumi, and soon after he hands her a notebook.  It has a title in Japanese, but, again, it is not translated.
[image: Rumi receiving notebook]

As she puts down the notebook, you see Seki-kun holding the microphone.
[image: Seki-kun holding microphone for Rumi]

...

[image: Rumi saying something like Yama Tay!]

Yama Tay!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more meta than anything.

What Seki-kun is doing is providing Rumi a script for the *Tonari no Seki-kun* anime, handing her a mic, and expecting her to read a line.  This is further evidenced by the fact that he has what looks like key animations on his laptop **of Rumi**, specifically where she's meant to say something.

What she says is やめて (yamete), which is Japanese for "stop it", or "knock it off". This is *also* a line in the song itself, and is coincidentally sung when Seki is looking for her line.

(As an exercise to the astute watcher, keep a close eye on this reaction after this line is said/sung. You won't be disappointed.)

Answer (score 2):

Even I freaking low that OP, She does say "Yamete" which roughly translates to "Stop", It can also be interpreted as please stop or anything along those lines depending on the tone it is said in.